# Emoji Rendering Issue after posting a Newsfeed

Tags: javascript, emojione

On posting my newsfeed message including unicodes of images e.g. `\\ud83d\\ude01\\ud83d\\ude06\\ud83d\\ude03\\ud83d\\ude04test`, it displays `\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�test` . I am using 'Emojione' javascript library for converting the unicode to Image."

After calling ajax, I render newsfeed data by converting the unicode data by calling function `unescapeUnicode(emojiRegExp)`

```
function unescapeUnicode( str ) {
    return str.replace( /\\u([a-fA-F0-9]{4})/g, function(g, m1) {
         return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(m1, 16));
    });
}
```

I expect the output 'test', but the actual output is '"\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�test"'

Comment: What system are you using? The response you get is similar to that on an unsupported OS, such as Windows 7 or a Linux distro without emoji's installed.

Comment: Also, for me your code is actually working nicely! I get the expected emoji output.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04LTS. But as soon as I render after ajax call, it didn't able to convert the unicodes with image tags. In backend, this process takes place before submission of newsfeed content. <pre> <code> def utf16_hex_to_unicode_char(utf16_hex)
    hex = utf16_hex.gsub("\\u",'')
    return [hex].pack('H*').force_encoding('utf-16be').encode('utf-8')
  end

  def replace_all_utf16_hex(string)
    return string.gsub(/(\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}){2}/){|hex| utf16_hex_to_unicode_char(hex)}
  end